# Passing numeric value to a function

Tags: interactive, arguments, completing-read

I have got the following function but want to pass a numeric mode even if `completing-read` asks for a string.

```
(defun mycompany (mode)
  "Enables or disables company text completion in buffer."
  (interactive
   (list
    (let ( (cseq '("enable" "disable")) )
      (completing-read "Mode: " cseq nil t "disable"))))
  
 (pcase mode
   ("enable"  (global-company-mode  1))
   ("disable" (global-company-mode -1))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear, alas.  Is this all you're looking for?

```lisp
(defun mycompany (mode)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (list (if (equal "enable" (completing-read "Mode: "
                                              '("enable" "disable")
                                              nil
                                              t
                                              "disable"))
             1
          -1)))
  (global-company-mode mode))
```